# Is it possible to run standard mechanical shifting on a Scott Foil Premium frame?

Tags: maintenance, product-rec, parts, frames, best-practice

The Scott Foil Premium is the highest end frame available from Scott Sports, and it is designed to run an electronic drive train, routed internally.

The original reports were that this frame would be available to run either a mechanical or electronic drive train, but that information appears to no longer be available.

I would like to run mechanical Campagnolo Super Record on this frame. The question is, does the frame have the necessary cable routing and cable stops for a mechanical drivetrain, or is it electronic **only**.

I am interested in the Foil Premium, in part because of the graphic design, but I don't want to order the frame, and then find out I can't run the drive train I want. I could play safe and order the Team Issue, but I don't like the color as well, and I may want to run electronic at some future date, so I like the flexibility of the Foil Premium, if it works.

[image: Scott Foil Premium]

It will likely take a physical examination of the frame to answer this question accurately.

[image: Scott Foil Team Issue]

This is the Scott Foil Team Issue, which is designed for mechanical shifting, for sure.

Comment: Seems like Scott Sports would gladly tell you? Especially for a new high end frame.

Comment: I've asked. I was told they needed to check, 2weeks ago. I've had no further response since.

Comment: There is always the possibility to use one single piece of cable router from shifter to derailer (no cable stops needed). Perhaps if it is done carefully, the end result is visually compatible with the whole high-end design.

Comment: The bottom bracket on the Foil for the mechanical shifter has a 2cm x 2.5cm cutout for the BB cable guide. It also has a hole drilled in the top of the drive side chain stay, right behind the seat tube. I need to determine if the Di2 version also has these holes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm holding off on the electronic shifting until it becomes more mainstream and the price drops...just a tad...

Comment: In a shop the other day oggling bikes... on one model, the shifting system was worth more than the rest of the bike! Wow!

Comment: If you are looking at the Dura Ace level, it's pretty common, and Campy EPS is worse. The Ultegra is actually a newer, more user friendly design, and it has a much better price point. On top of which, the Dura Ace design will be released for 2013 any day now, with major design changes and improvements rumored. It'll be a while before I can buy the group I want.

Comment: Voted to close. This is entirely a self motivated question. It has no relevance other than that the poster just wants to say,"look at my new bike".

Comment: Very nice though.

Comment: @wdypdx22: Interesting. Actually, when I asked the question, I had not yet seen the Foil Premium frame. I had only seen the Foil 10, which is designed as a mechanical shifting frame. I wanted the confirmation of whether to order the 10 or the Premium. Instead, I ended up having to order it blind. I was not able to use the mechanical shifting without drilling holes in the frame. So I posted an answer, once I had one. If I'd wanted to brag, I'd have posted photos of my own bike, not stock web photos of the frame.

Comment: Can you provide pics of this conversion please.i have a scott foil 15 im about to make take a mechanical groupset so any advice would be appreciated

Comment: A 2013 article about the Foil 15 has this quote, “The redundant port at the top of the downtube on the non-driveside is an unfortunate reminder of the bike's provision for mechanical groupsets.” So Ask this as a fresh question (welcome to the site) and include photos of your Foil 15 in key places 

Comment: @KevinMoore Does your Foil 15 have the cable routingbplug in the bottom bracket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Foil Premium frame does not have the factory routing for mechanical shifting. It is designed for Shimano Di2 or Campagnolo EPS electronic shifting only.

I was able to modify the frame successfully to accept normal cable routing, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you are very confident in your skills with drill and dremel. And of course it voids the warranty.

Edit:

To respond to a couple of requests for more information in comments, I've added some detail about this frame mod.

To be clear, this very much voids your warranty, and requires precise and careful work to avoid destroying the frame.

FYI, my mod was successful, but was very risky. I literally had to cut a large hole of a very specific shape and position in the BB shell.  I also had to drill a hole through the pre-molded cable stop section at the head tube, as well as through the chainstay by the rear derailleur.

The holes needed to fit these parts and be very, very precisely placed in the frame. 
[image]
I was able to make a pattern out of paper and take very careful measurements From a Foil 10 frame. Without that ability, I would not have been confident enough to do this mod.

Comment: hello could you add a image or a description on how you managed to do this